# Website doesn't load properly on webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a fragment, that includes a simple webview and textview.
I'm trying to load a site, but it doesn't load well.

[image: ChromeBrowser working properly]

[image: webView in fragment don't work well]

I googled and didn't find a solution. I think that the sourch of the problem is 
the site itself https://m.headstart.co.il/#/main?id=17863 , but I don't understand web languages well enough to understand if the problem is really there.
What is the problem? and how can I make the site load properly on the webview?
Thanks in advance.

the code block:

```
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_campaign, container, false);

        String address_campaign = "http://www.headstart.co.il/project.aspx?id=17863";

        WebView wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
//        UI setting
//        wv.setInitialScale(1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
//        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        wv.loadUrl(address_campaign);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return v;
```

the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ContackRWBForDonate">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Help us build a better community"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:foregroundGravity="top|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundMainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

Comment: Code looks like perfect .

Comment: Which version of android are using? WebView have a lot of problems in versions previous than kitkat.

Comment: I'm using MIN SDK API 15, which is previous to kitkat. Do you have any soultion?@AgustinSivoplás

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are missing is more configuration of your **WebViews settings**.
My guess is that you need to allow Dom, local data storage and more.

Add these permissions and if they solve it try finding the unnecessary ones.

```
wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess();
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess();
wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled();
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled();
```

I **also** suggest you try out the new API created for **Chrome Custom Tabs** - creating your own Chrome-tab in your app.
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Content access & file access are enabled by default.

Comment: Setting database enabled requires you to `setDatabasePath` where storage API databases should be saved.